# Translation from Python to Batch for a CSV program

Tags: python, csv, batch-file

I really need help with using a batch file to do the following:

I need to read in a text file line by line and, for each entry of a given CSV file that starts with an element found in the line of text file, write it into a new CSV file.

Or, in other words:

Read the following

```
example.csv
Page, Pageviews, Bounce Rate, /category/apples, 1029, 67%, /category/brussel-sprout, 3409, 92%, /category/orange, 1233, 87%
```

Then read the following text file line by line:

```
example.txt
/category/apples
/category/orange
```

And create this file:

```
new.csv
Page, Pageviews, Bounce Rate, /category/apples, 1029, 67%, /category/orange, 1233, 87%
```

So far I've worked on this project through a batch file that takes each individual address of a list, checks to see if it has a certain header, and then writes the extension in a list. Unfortunately this isn't enough, as I also need to then regenerate the tables from the original CSV -- but only the ones with a header. I was attempting to do this via Python but it was proving too cumbersome (and system boundaries made it not feasible to write Python, anyway). If you'd like to see code you can click on my questions through my profile, but they don't concern this piece. What I have left to do is this, and I ask for clarity and ideas as my strengths don't lie in BAT but C++ (and no, that's not an option).

Thank you for the help. This community has (with some exception) proved excellent grounds for learning valuable lessons and pushing me to succeed.

This is where I was headed with Python:

```
import csv

lines = []
with open('output.txt','r') as f:
    for line in f.readlines():
        lines.append(line[:-1])

with open('corrected.csv','w') as correct:
    writer = csv.writer(correct, dialect = 'excel')
    with open('input.csv', 'r') as mycsv:
        reader = csv.reader(mycsv)
        for row in reader:
            if row[0] not in lines:
                writer.writerow(row)
```

Comment: If you think that doing this in Python is cumbersome, I can't imagine why you think that a batch file will be better.  Don't you have any other options, like PowerShell?

Comment: Don't think so, no. Is there no simple way to read a CSV file the same way as a text file and say something like 1. check if the object you're on = any line of text in the text file 2(if yes). write the object and all five objects following into a new file 2(if no). move 5 objects and repeat.

Comment: Oh god, text processing in windows Batch? Your effort would be far better spent figuring out how to make Python run on your target.

Comment: Are you saying Python doesn't run on your system, or that you can't get your Python code to work?  And what version of Windows are you using?  If it is even vaguely up-to-date, it has PowerShell.  And even if it doesn't, you still most likely have options like VBScript/JScript, which would be much less painful than batch.  (But my first choice out of all of these would be Python.)

Comment: You forgot to mention that you have Unicode complications with your data ...

Comment: I'm saying it would take quite a bit of time to make Python accessible to all on the system, but I'd rather do that and use Python than spend a lot more time wasting hours on batch. @JohnMachin, I'm really sorry about that, I didn't know. Noted for future posting.

Comment: @JamesRoseman: I'm the one to be sorry; I was wrong; I was confusing you with another enquirer, who did have Unicode problems with csv.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just write the Batch file you need. However, I don't know the .csv file format, so I assumed several details. These are my assumptions:

- The .csv file contains just ASCII text with no CR-LF separators.
- Each .csv element is separated by comma AND DO NOT CONTAIN SPACES (this limitation may be solved).
- The size of the input .csv file is below 8 KB (required to read its contents in a Batch variable).
- The .csv data is comprised of groups of 3 elements: a header with 3 elements, and each category with 3 elements.
- Both the categories in the .csv file and the lines in the .txt file are placed in ASCII ascending order.
- The categories in the .txt file ARE included in the .csv.

This is the Batch file:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
rem Read .csv data and split/store its elements in csv array.
set /P csv_data=< example.csv
set i=0
for %%e in (!csv_data!) do (
    set /A i+=1
    set csv[!i!]=%%e
)
rem Create the new.csv file with its header.
echo %csv[1]%, %csv[2]%, %csv[3]%> new.csv
rem Process each line of the text file.
set i=1
for /F %%l in (example.txt) do call :SeekAndWriteCsv %%l
goto :eof

:SeekAndWriteCsv
rem Seek the matching csv category.
set /A i+=3
if not !csv[%i%]! == %1 goto SeekAndWriteCsv
rem Write the matching category to the new.csv file.
set /A j=i+1, k=i+2
echo , !csv[%i%]!, !csv[%j%]!, !csv[%k%]!>> new.csv
```

That is it. Please, try it and let me know any problem you get.

**EDIT**

I just realized of an error: the new.csv categories are placed in separated lines. To fix that, make these changes:

Change these lines

```
rem Create the new.csv file with its header.
echo %csv[1]%, %csv[2]%, %csv[3]%> new.csv
```

by these ones

```
rem Create the new.csv file with its header.
echo/> enter.txt
set /P dummy=%csv[1]%, %csv[2]%, %csv[3]%< enter.txt > new.csv
```

Change this line

```
echo , !csv[%i%]!, !csv[%j%]!, !csv[%k%]!>> new.csv
```

by this one

```
set /P dummy=, !csv[%i%]!, !csv[%j%]!, !csv[%k%]!< enter.txt >> new.csv
```

Also, to avoid errors with some special characters, insert quotes in this line

```
    set csv[!i!]=%%e
```

this way

```
    set "csv[!i!]=%%e"
```

Comment: I'm going to fully test it tomorrow on the Company system, we'll see what happens! Thank you!

Comment: It can fail if the csv contains exclamation marks `!` and it's hard to solve that

Comment: No exclamation points in data. But good point. Thank you all for the help and assistance!

Answer (score 1):

Windows (DOS) batch language is ill suited for this kind of task.  While it may be possible, the resulting script is certain to be cumbersome, convoluted, and confusing.

Python is a fine solution, and it's not clear in the posting why you don't want to use it.  If your concern is installing Python, consider [py2exe](http://www.py2exe.org/) which allows you to create a standalone python executable.

Comment: @jdigital: Excuse me. In my opinion, the Batch solution is clear and direct, and easy to follow even by people that don't know Batch... :(

Comment: @Aacini, let's see how other StackOverflow users vote on this.

Comment: @Aacini: I applaud you for your effort, and I'll admit your code is much less scary than I expected (I wasn't even sure it was possible). But it's still not nearly as easy to read as almost any Python solution, and it's harder to modify if the requirements change.  And that 8 KB data size limit is also a pretty severe constraint.

Comment: My point is: nobody can express an opinion about something they don't know. The Python program above is obscure to me, but this just means I don't know Python. Of course, I don't say that Batch is better than Python: it is not. What I say is that many people think that Batch have no value because a short contact they have 20 years ago or after seen one of the Batch "solutions" published. The answer of jdigital (that received an upvote!) and the comment of Chriszuma (with 3 upvotes) and yourself just proved my point. I just say: to opine about Batch, first understand its current capabilities.

Comment: @Aacini: No one said batch has no value. What most of us are saying is that *in our opinion* Python is going to be easier and quicker. Now, you will see that your answer got more votes than jdigital, and was accepted. So why are you complaining? I still believe that your solution is not as flexible as using Python. Look at all those assumptions you put at the beginning of your answer. In Python, it is almost trivial to get rid of all of them, whereas it is difficult or impossible to get rid of some of them in batch. (For example, what happens if the input CSV is 8 megabytes?)

Comment: @JohnY: Really? Chriszuma: "Oh god, text processing in Batch?", jdigital: "Batch language is ill suited for this kind of task", yourself: "I wasn't even sure it was possible" and "it is difficult or impossible to get rid of some _limitations_ in batch". Do you know Batch enough to be sure of this last assertion? Again, the point is this: if you want to say that Python is good, just say it. Why all of you must add that Batch is bad? (or not flexible, or slower, or difficult, or...). Just think of this: ALL the comments with an upvote in this topic are those that attack Batch! Curios, isn't it?